# downstream jenkins job does not get aborted if upstream job is aborted

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, abort

Two jenkins jobs are connected as: Upstream job is a pipeline and triggers a freestyle job.

Is it possible in Jenkins to get the following scenario:

If downstream job is aborted the upstream job gets aborted. 
But if the upstream job is aborted the downstream job should not abort, but continue running.

```
Upstream job :
    node('upstream_node'){
    build job: 'downstream_job', wait:true, propagate:false
    }
```

I have tried all possible combinations with 'wait' and 'propagate' options, but non of them will work.

Comment: Sounds like instead 2 jobs you should have 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `propagate:true` instead of `false`.

This is from the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) :

> - propagate (optional)
>     If set, then if the downstream build is anything
>     but successful (blue ball), this step fails. If disabled, then this
>     step succeeds even if the downstream build is unstable, failed, etc.;
>     use the result property of the return value as needed.

Comment: The propagate:true satisfies one condition. 1 - If downstream job is aborted the upstream job gets aborted. But it will also do : 2 - If upstream job is aborted the downstream job gets aborted. While what I want is the nr 1. and 3- If upstream job is aborted the downstream continues

Comment: Then I think it's with `wait:false`. There is an option to block on downstream job with the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) but I'm not sure if's the same as `wait`. You should try

Comment: wait:false does not satisfy condition nr. 1. Whatever happens with the downstream job, the upstream will not be affected since does not wait about it. Already tried all combinations. While the options from 'Parameterized Trigger Plugin' can't be used in a pipeline only a freestyle job.  But thank you anyway for your reply

Comment: Oh indeed, but now I don't understand the purpose, why would you continue the downstream job if you already canceled the upstream one ?

Comment: Because the upstream job is such a process that if it has already started it should finish, regardless of what happens. It should not stop, otherwise breaks some other things.  But the result of it is not always considered. It is important that once started finishes till the end.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Using the lock plugin in Jenkins

[How can I block a Jenkins 2.x Pipeline job while dependent jobs are building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845882/how-can-i-block-a-jenkins-2-x-pipeline-job-while-dependent-jobs-are-building)